# Netbeans 8.0.1 and PhoneGap 3.5.0

Tags: html, cordova, netbeans, jscript

I have Netbeans 8.0.1 and PhoneGap 3.5.0 installed but for some reason, Netbeans wont let me create a new PhoneGap/Cordova project. I read somewhere that PhoneGap changed its versioning format so Netbeans cant read the new one. Is this true? And if so how does one solve this?

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans supports Cordova, not PhoneGap. Cordova version 3.5.0 has e.g. following version format `3.5.0-0.2.6` which is supported. The issue could be also in missing Git, make sure you have Git installed and on `$PATH`

Update: Cordova changed the version output in 3.7.0 and it does not work with NetBeans. You can install older version by `npm install -g cordova@3.6.3-0.2.13` as a workaround. The issue is tracked [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=248087)